# mi base de datos registra datos pero lo hace en blanco. PHP POO

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

hola alguien que me pueda ayudar con una consulta ya que no encuentro solucion por ningun lado...  mi base de datos no registra a los clientes.. bueno de hecho si registra pero lo hace en blanco... y cuando refresco la pagina también hace un registro en blanco... (los dos primeros registros ya estaban, fue de una base de datos que copie) alguien que me pueda ayudar ya llevo dos semanas y no encuentro el error.. al parecer mi codigo es correcto, con metodos get y set. porque segui un tutorial de programacion orientado a objetos, pero el del tutorial nunca me contesto mi consulta...  de hecho todos los errores que he tenido los he corregido solo con ayuda del archivo ERROR_LOG .. y bueno ya el ultimo error que me imprime es este:

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/lunapict/public_html/Vistas/Registro.php:6) in /home/lunapict/public_html/Vistas/Registro.php on line 192
saludos a todos. 
[image: base de datos registro vacio]

ESTE es mi codigo  ARCHIVO registro.php

```
 `

        <?php
        include '../DAO/MetodosDAO.php';
        ?>

<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-2 animate-box">
          <h2 align="center" style= "margin-top: 80px; ">Registro de usuarios</h2>

         <form  method="POST" id="registroclientes">
              <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name" class="sr-only">Nombre</label>
              <input name="txtNom" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" id="name"   required  >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email" class="sr-only">Correo</label>
              <input name="txtCor" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="correo" id="email"  required >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="message" class="sr-only">Password</label>
              <input name="txtPas"  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"  id="password" required >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">

           <button type="submit" value="GuardarDatos" class="btn btn-primary"  name="btnEnviar" id="btnRegistro">Guardar datos</button>
           </div>
         </form>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>


    <?php 
    if (isset($_REQUEST ['btnEnviar'])) {
        $nom=$_REQUEST['txtNom'];
        $cor=$_REQUEST['txtCor'];
        $pas=$_REQUEST['txtPas'];


        $objCli=new Cliente (0, $nom, $cor, $pas);

        $metodos=new MetodosDAO();
        $i=$metodos->RegistrarCliente ($objCli);

        if ($i==1)
        header ("location: Cesta.php");

        else
        header ("location: Catalogo.php?error=no se inserto el registro");
        }

    ?>
```

`

y luego ARCHIVO metodosDAO.php

```
include '../Utils/ConexionDB.php';
require '../BEANS/Cliente.php';
include '../BEANS/Pedido.php';
include '../BEANS/DetallePedido.php';

 public function RegistrarCliente (Cliente $cli) {
         $cnx=new ConexionDB ();
         $cn=$cnx->getConexion ();
         $res = $cn->prepare ("insert into clientes values (0, '$cli->nomCli ', '$cli->correo ', '$cli->pas ')" );
         $i=$res->execute ();
         $cn=null;
         return $i; 
    }
```

y luego la Cliente.php

```
  <?php 

class Cliente

{

    public $codCli;
    public $nomCli;
    public $correo;
    public $pas;

function _construct ($codCli, $nomCli, $correo, $pas) {

     $this->codCli = $codCli ;
     $this->nomCli = $nomCli ;
     $this->correo = $correo ;
     $this->pas = $pas ;

}

public function _setCodCli($codCli){
  $this->codCli = $codCli;
 }

public function _setNomCli($nomCli){
  $this->nomCli = $nomCli;
 }

public function _setCorreo($correo){
  $this->correo = $correo;
 }

 public function _setPas($pas){
  $this->pas = $pas;
 }



public function getCodCli() {
    return $this->codCli;
 }

public function getNomCli() {
    return $this->nomCli;
 }

public function getCorreo() {
    return $this->correo;
 }

public function getPas() {
    return $this->pas;
 }



}

?>
```

no encuentro el error. me habian dicho que no seteaba bien los datos a mi tabla, ya lo ultimo que logre fue que me imprimiera esto. [image: var_dump($ObjCli);] pero ya estoy deseperado porque he intentado todo y buscado la informacion, con los que saben y no saben.. :( si alguien pudiera asesorarme. igual podriamos ponernos de acuerdo $ saludos.

Comment: Lo digo al menos 10 veces al día en este sitio: **hay que depurar**. Si los datos te llegan nulos, depura los datos, en este caso, aquellos que usas para informar la instancia de la clase. De paso, hace falta coherencia, si el método del formulario es `post`, entonces usa `$_POST` y no `$_REQUEST`. Empecemos por el paso 1, haz un `var_dump($_POST);` y dinos lo que muestra. Esa es la 1ª depuración que debes hacer. Anota esto: **si aprendes a depurar te vas a ahorrar días, horas, semanas... rompiéndote el coco** para adivinar dónde está el problema.

Comment: Hay más errores que iremos viendo por parte. Los `header` están mal puestos, cuando los usas no debe haber ninguna salida por pantalla antes de ellos, por eso tienes los Warning en el error log, porque antes de los `header` tienes salida por pantalla (el formulario). Significa que tu código debe ser repensado, organizado de otra forma. Sería interesante implementar Ajax para casos como estos. Luego, otro error es que los `prepare` del `INSERT` no se escriben así. No sé de dónde aprendiste, pero al parecer la metodología de esa fuente no es muy buena.